# Probability and standard deviation questions need some help

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

A recent study by the American Highway Patrolman’s Association revealed that 65%
of American drivers use their seatbelts. A sample of 12 drivers on major highways was randomly selected.

a. Find the probability that seven of the drivers are wearing seatbelts.

b. How many of the drivers would be expected to be wearing their seatbelt?

c. Calculate the standard deviation for this distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background:

[image]

In *Mathematica*:

```
N@Binomial[12, 7] (.65^7 (1 - .65)^(12-7)
```

a) ${12 \choose 7} .65^7 (1-.65)^{12-7} = .2039$

```
Mean[BinomialDistribution[12, .65]]
```

b) $ .65 \times 12 = 7.8$

```
Variance[BinomialDistribution[12, .65]]
```

c) $Var = n p (1-p) = 12 \times 0.65 (1 - 0.65) = 2.73$

Comment: Hmm just curious what program did you use to graph the pmf? Is that R or Python or something? I like it.

Comment: *Mathematica*...

Answer (score 1):

If you like using RStudio (R statistical computing environment), then use the following command lines:

$a$. $\hspace{2mm}$ ${\tt dbinom(7,12,0.65)}$ $\hspace{2mm}$ since the binomial distribution is the probability mass function (pmf) 
$$
b(x) = b(x; 12,0.65) = 
\begin{cases} 
\binom{12}{x} (0.65)^x(0.35)^{12-x} &\mbox{ if } x=0,1,2,\ldots, 12, \\ 
\qquad \qquad 0 & \mbox{ otherwise}, \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

$b$. $\hspace{2mm}$ ${\tt 12*.65}$ $\hspace{2mm}$ since the expected value for a binomial distribution is $E[X]=np$, where $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of success (the percentage of American drivers using their seatbelts),

$c$. $\hspace{2mm}$ 
${\tt sqrt(12*(.65)*(.35))}$ $\hspace{2mm}$ since the variance for the binomial distribution is $V(X)=np(1-p)$. So the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, i.e., $\sigma=\sigma_X = \sqrt{V(X)}$.

$\color{green}{\textbf{Plotting}.}$
If you want to plot this binomial distribution (on a plane), then use the following command lines on RStudio: 
$$
\begin{align*}
&{\tt x <- seq(0, 12, by = 1) } \\ 
&{\tt y <- dbinom(x, 12, 0.65) } \\ 
&{\tt png(file = "dbinom.png") } \\ 
&{\tt plot(x,y) } \\ 
&{\tt dev.off() } \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
and you'll see the following png file saved to your computer. 
[image: dbinom]

Comment: the second answer turns out to be 7.8, but in reality it can not be 7.8 people, is it essential to make it 7 or follow maths logic and be 8 people? thanks

Comment: Part $b.$ is asking for the mean, so the mean being $7.8$ is ok. You can also write an additional sentence (if this is your homework) that the mean is between $7$ to $8$ people.